# how to integrate message broker (Nats) with laravel?

Tags: laravel, nats.io

Currently I have a project running on laravel and I want to use nats as our message broker. I tried to use https://github.com/flownative/nats but my question is where should I put pub subs code?

```php
$nats->publish('foo', 'Hello World');

// Simple asynchronous subscriber
$nats->subscribe('foo', function($message) {
    printf("\nReceived a message: %s\n", $message->getBody());
});
```

I tried to use PHP artisan queue but that is not working since it has to be triggered by calling dispatch method. If so where should I call dispatch method? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no community package for supporting NATS in Laravel (from what I can see), I think using that NATS PHP package will not solve the infrastructure you're trying to build as Pub/Sub, since you would have to wrap up NATS php package within a custom Queue driver in Larval.

I would highly recommend to use SNS/SQS for the Pub/Sub infrastructure, luckily I already made a package for that. it's quite easy to use, where you can define Subscribers class and Publishers if you want that, Also it does support the Standard and FIFO SQS/SNS.

Check it out: https://github.com/amranidev/micro-bus

Answer (score 0):

The Question of OP is where to put the *pubsub code*.

My Solutions is to place the pubsub logic into a custom artisan command.

In Laravel, long-running tasks like in this case listening for messages on a message broker are typically handled by Artisan commands.

A basic subscribtion inside of a custom artisan command can look like follows:

```
[...]

$client->connect();

$client->subscribe('my-event', function ($message) {
    // Handle the message
    $this->info("Received message!");
});

while(true) {
    $client->process();
}

[...]
```

With the while loop we keep the client connection and subscription alive so that we are still able to send or receive messages.

This [article](https://fly.io/laravel-bytes/servers-in-sync/) provides more detailed instructions on how to create the custom Artisan command for this use case.